# Spin and Parity of $^{17}_8 O$ excited states

Tags: nuclear-physics, protons, neutrons, pauli-exclusion-principle

$^{17}_8 O$ [quoted here](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=80017) has a spin of 5/2 and parity of +1 for the ground state, I agree with this, the unpaired neutron is in the $1d_{1/2}$ state so l = 2, spin = 5/2.

Now I want to figure out the spin an parity of the first two excited states, but how do I know which proton and which neutron move up.

I am thinking that the first excited state is where the unpaired neutron moves to the $2s_{1/2}$ state, so that l = 2, and spin = 1/2, thus the parity remains 1.

But how do I figure out the configuration for the second excited state.

Comment: On the same LBL site there is [a full set of level drawings](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/sumframe.htm). Now all I have to do is recall how to read them. Here's the [one for A=17 (PDF link)](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/pdf/17.pdf).

Comment: For any future visitors, the $2s_{1/2}$
 is the next excited state only by some authors (e.g. http://dommelen.net/quantum2/style_a/ntsm.html)... Other authors might have the $1d_{5/2}$
 as above the $1d_{3/2}$
 which would predict a different first excited state (namely $J^P={\frac32}^−$). This shows the deficiencies in the nuclear shell model. I believe the different orderings are due to to the strength of the spin-orbit coupling used.

Answer (score 1):

A better reference for determining these nuclear states from experiment is [NuDat](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/nudat2/getdataset.jsp?nucleus=17O&unc=nds) at Brookhaven. Figuring out the interaction energy of a neutron in any particular energy level with a $^{16}O$ core is extremely difficult. There is some model intuition that can help you, as you used for the first excited state. In this case, the second excited state $1/2^-$ must be more complicated. I would guess that it results from a neutron from the closed core joining the extra neutron in the d-shell, leaving a hole in the p-shell that gives the quantum numbers here. As you can see, there's a huge extra energy needed to make this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by others, you can check the experimental spin in NuDat database. However, if you would like to figure out the spin using the single-particle configuration, the results are generally not very reliable for excited state at higher energies. Usually, using a shell model code would provide a more accuracy and realistic result as I mention in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/639127/low-energy-excited-states-of-13c/749221#749221)